# Arabic: how to conveniently enter dagger-vowels (AKA miniature vowels) and alif-wasla with PC keyboard

Tags: keyboard, arabic, diacritics

I would like to enter `dagger-alif`, `dagger-waw`, and `dagger-ya`
(AKA miniature alif, miniature wow, and miniature ya) as well
as `alif-wasla` with a PC Arabic keyboard. These marks are used
to help the reader with pronounciation.

The dagger/miniature vowels typically appear over letters in textbooks
and dictionaries to show that a LONG vowel must be pronounced after
a consonant even though such long vowel does not appear after the consonant.
The miniature vowel is omitted from regular script such as in newspapers.

For example the word `هٰذَا` here appears with a `miniature-alif` over the
letter `ه` (and a fatha over the letter `ذ`) despite in regular script
the same word would be simply written as `هذا`.

The alif-wasla has a small mim in its initial position over the alif
indicating that the alif is silent and looks as follows: `ٱ`.
(this must not be confused with alif-madda which indicates
that a hamza followed by a long aa is to be pronounced and
is written with a tilda over an alif as follows: `آ`).

A picture of the IBM PC arabic keyboard layout can be found here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_keyboard . The following
is a picture of a PC keyboard from `DELL` which was more or less
the Arabic PC keyboard I could find on the market to also display
arabic language symbols corresponding to shift pressed:
[image: DELL PC Arabic keyboard]

As you can see the sought diacritics are missing from the keyboard inputs.

These symbols are also partially described here: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_diacritics

The following link
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/671/index.htm
shows that I can type `alif-wasla` as `ALT01649` and
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0670/index.htm
shows that I can for instance type the `miniature superscript aliph` as `ALT01648`
but this only seems to work in `MS Word`.
But I cannot find a way to type these in `LibreOffice`. If anyone know
of some convenient manner of entering these other than cut and paste, which is what I
used above, then please let me know. Can I use for instance `MSKLC` or is there some
way of entering the missing symbols with Unicode shortcuts? Thanks.

Comment: They are not missing. Select the correct keyboard layout (not the default EN layout). Then try `shift + A` to enter َ , `shift + H` to enter آ and so on.

Comment: No, I was not asking about the fatha, kasra, damma signs and the aliph-hamza or aliph-madda, which is what you point out here. I was asking about dagger long vowels and aliph-wasla, which are different. Please cut and paste the example script I posted into Word or LibreOffice in a 72 point font and what you will be able to clearly see is that what I am asking for is not what you have just pointed out.

Comment: Hi @JohnSonderson , have you found the answer? I need to know the same thing.

Comment: Are you using LibreOffice in Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 3):

The daggar alif is part of the Arabic typesetting font symbols. That's a free font which is you can find downloadable. Then you type the letter you want... for example the ha of haadhaa , set the cursor on that letter,  and use INSERT.. SYMBOL and you will find that alif with other diacritics --- here's an example.

**هٰذا**

Peace

Answer (score 3):

Yes, its not available on keyboard on Windows or Mac. It's a symbol to be inserted. If not on MS Word, other quick way is to google using the simple word and copy past the rich text result. HTH.

Update: On Mac, its available by using Alt + H in Arabic keyboard mode

Comment: Thank you! I needed this on a mac and this was the answer! Alt+6 for alif wasala!

Answer (score 1):

Not all characters are accessible by keyboards (by default). To be able to insert special character conveniently from your keyboard you need to create a custom keyboard layout. Assuming you're on windows, use [The Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx).

Comment: What about entering the Unicode characters in LibreOffice without using MSKLC. How can I accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In LibreOffice (and Microsoft Word), you can **type** the Unicode code first then press <kbd>Alt+X</kbd> to transform it into the actual character/glyph etc.
For example, writing `هٰذَا` would be writing ه then typing the superscript alef Unicode code `0670` then press <kbd>Alt+X</kbd> and it will become هٰ then type the rest ذَا.

You can just google the unicode code for certain characters, search [here](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/) or see the full Arabic characters  chart from the [official PDF](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0600.pdf).

Ref:

1. [Unicode Input on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#In_platform-independent_applications)
2. [Unicode charts](https://www.unicode.org/charts/)